# What is this plant my grandma used to give me?

Tags: identification, edible

When I was a kid, my grandma would grow this one specific plant. There were two different kinds, one with purple flowers and one with I think white? I remember she would give me these and let me eat the stems. I remember they were super sour but super delicious, and they wouldn't just grow in the big plant pot she had in her backyard but also around the area. It was either the leaves of the plant or maybe the petals but they were also edible and they tasted...like leaves but still yummy. I've been looking for this plant for years but my mom doesn't remember the plant at all and my grandma doesn't either!! Someone pls help I've been trying to grow the plant myself for agessss

Comment: Welcome! If we want to have at least a chance of identifying your mystery plant, we need a lot more details, starting with where in the world this plant grew, and then everything else that you can remember - and a few clarifications, e.g. did  you eat the stems, the leaves or the petals (or all of it)? Do you remember whether your grandmother used the plant for cooking?

Comment: Lemongrass or ginger in Thailand or Jamaica? Leaves or stem. Purple or white flowers. Sour but good. Sketch it for us, please.

Answer (score 1):

Might it be [Wood Sorrel](https://www.wildedible.com/wild-food-guide/wood-sorrel)?

[image: Image of wood sorrel with yellow flowers]

> Wood Sorrel (genus Oxalis), or sourgrass, is a medium sized weed that occurs throughout most of North America.
>
> Within the genus Oxalis, there are several hundred species.
>
> Wood sorrel looks similar to clover and tends to get misidentified as clover.

....

> Is wood sorrel edible? Yes! Oxalis literally means "sour" and it gets that name from its oxalic acid content.

It grew wild where I grew up in Kentucky, and I was very fond of eating the leaves and buds because of their sour taste. And I will admit that I called it "clover". I always ate the yellow flower variety, but apparently [white and purple are not uncommon](https://wildadirondacks.org/adirondack-wildflowers-common-wood-sorrel-oxalis-montana.html).

> Common Wood Sorrel flowers appear singly (one to a stalk). The symmetrical flowers are small (3/4 inch wide), with five white petals that are deeply notched. The petals have deep pink or purple veins and are splashed with yellow near the base.

[image: Image of wood sorrel showing a largely white flower] [image: Violet Wood Sorrel]